# MySQL round weird bug

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing a really weird ¿bug? on mysql+php right now.
Is a simple select, in the following example i'm using multiple fields to try to explain my problem:

- "field" is 11.5
- $phpvar is 1.15

MySQL query:

```
select round(field * " . $phpvar . " ,2) as a1, 
       round(field * 1.15 ,2) as a2, 
       round(11.5 * " . $phpvar . " ,2) as a3, 
       round(11.5 * 1.15 ,2) as a4, 
       field * " . $phpvar . " as a5 
from ...
```

ok, i'm trying to get 13.23. `"field" * $phpvar = 13.225`, so using round(13.225,2) I should get 13.23, right? well, yes and no.

query results:

- a1 [round(field * " . $phpvar . " ,2)] => 13.22
- a2 [round(field * 1.15 ,2)] => 13.22
- a3 [round(11.5 * " . $phpvar . " ,2)] => 13.23
- a4 [round(11.5 * 1.15 ,2)] => 13.23
- a5 [field * " . $phpvar . "] => 13.225 (without round)

what am I missing? how is it possible, when it comes to use "field", my result gets a fake round?

Comment: How is field defined in the database?

Comment: select field * 1.15 and 11.5 * 1.15 without rounding as well, as a6 and a7 and post the result.

Comment: Anigel "field" is DOUBLE;; 

jishi select field * 1.15 returns 13.225;; 
select 11.5 * 1.15 returns 13.25;; 

Nick as far as I know, ceil() on mysql returns "the smallest integer value not less than X", without decimals

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: I guess it is possible that 11.5 in the DB column could be stored as 11.499999999999~ thus 11.4999999999~ * 1.15 would be 13.224999999~ thus round(13.224999999999~, 2) will result in 13.22. It depends on the column type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is how the DOUBLE and FLOAT values are stored.

It is possible (and probable) that values like 11.5 or 22.475 coul be stored in approximated values like 11.499999999999~ or 22.475000000000000001 thus some calculations or roundings could lead to incorrect results.

It is always better to store float values into a **DECIMAL** coulmn type where the value is stored exactly with all the decimal digits and is not approximated.

Comment: Thanks, using DECIMAL works right, I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: @shadyyx so when would you use float and double since they kinda stored differently ?

Answer (score 5):

Exact numeric literals (such as the `1.15` in all four of your examples and the `11.5` in your latter two) are [encoded](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/precision-math-numbers.html) using MySQL's `DECIMAL` type.

In your first two examples, the result of multiplying `field` (of type `DOUBLE`) with such literals is another `DOUBLE`, which is stored using [8-byte](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/storage-requirements.html) [IEEE Standard](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-type-overview.html) floating-point representation (i.e. [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)). However, in this representation `13.225`  encodes as `0x402A733333333333`, whose bits signify:

```
Sign           : 0b0

Biased exponent: 0b10000000010
               =   1026 (representation includes bias of +1023, therefore exp = 3)

Significand    : 0b[1.]1010011100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
               =   [1.]6531249999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
                    ^ hidden bit, not stored in binary representation
```

This equates to:

```
  (-1)^0 * 1.6531249999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 * 2^3
=         13.2249999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375000
```

Therefore, rounding this result to two decimal places yields `13.22` not `13.23`.

Performing the multiplication with two `DECIMAL` types, such as two literals as used in your latter two examples, results in another `DECIMAL`.  In this representation, `13.225` encodes in a [binary-coded decimal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/storage-requirements.html) format with exact precision and therefore the rounding operation results in `13.23` as expected.

As mentioned in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-float.html):

> Floating-point numbers sometimes cause confusion because they are approximate and not stored as exact values. A floating-point value as written in an SQL statement may not be the same as the value represented internally. Attempts to treat floating-point values as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies. The [`FLOAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-types.html) and [`DOUBLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-types.html) data types are subject to these issues. For [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-types.html) columns, MySQL performs operations with a precision of 65 decimal digits, which should solve most common inaccuracy problems.

If you are after exact precision, `DECIMAL` may be more suited to your requirements.  If you need the range/performance of `DOUBLE` but still wish to have the desired rounding outcome, you could [`CONVERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) the result of the multiplication to `DECIMAL` prior to rounding.