# Calculating tax correctly using Mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to re-calculate tax on a sale after it is entered into a database. I can calculate the information correctly before storing in the database, but calculating it from the database for reporting purposes has proved troublesome due to rounding errors.

The application displays an interface that allows one to add items and view the subtotal, taxes and totals.

Example input:

Item 1: 9.95

Item 2: 2.95

**Subtotal: 12.90**

Taxes (could be different for each item, but now they are all the same for each item)

2.900%: 0.37

1.000%: 0.13

1.100%: 0.14

3.000%: 0.39

*Tax Total*: 1.03

**Total: 13.93**

The way I calculate taxes before storing into database:

```
foreach Item as $price
{
  foreach Tax as $percent
  {
    $taxes[$percent]+=$price*($percent/100);
  }
}

foreach($taxes as $percent => $tax_amount)
{
  $taxes[$percent] = ROUND_TO_2_DECIMALS($tax_amount);
}
```

After calculating all this information I store the information in a database that can be retrieved later for reporting purposes.

Example Schema:

```
phppos_sales_items
- sale_id
- item_id
- price

phppos_sales_items_taxes
- sale_id
- item_id
- tax_percent
```

**Sample Data for phppos_sales_items table**

sale_id: 1, item_id: 1, item_unit_price: 9.95

sale_id: 1, item_id: 2, item_unit_price: 2.95

**Sample Data for phppos_sales_items_taxes table**

sale_id: 1, item_id: 1, percent: 2.90

sale_id: 1, item_id: 1, percent: 1.00

sale_id: 1, item_id: 1, percent: 1.10

sale_id: 1, item_id: 1, percent: 3.00

sale_id: 1, item_id: 2, percent: 2.90

sale_id: 1, item_id: 2, percent: 1.00

sale_id: 1, item_id: 2, percent: 1.10

sale_id: 1, item_id: 2, percent: 3.00

Sample Query to calculate tax for a sale

```
(SELECT SUM(tax) FROM (SELECT ROUND((item_unit_price)*(SUM(percent)/100),2) as tax
FROM phppos_sales_items
INNER JOIN phppos_sales_items_taxes USING (sale_id, item_id)
WHERE sale_id = 1
GROUP BY sale_id, item_id) as tax)
```

Output is `1.04` when I need to get `1.03`. This query works in most cases, but it fails a lot to when there are rounding problems.

I need to be able to generate summary informatation accuratly using sql. I am open to any suggestions on how to calculate information before the sale and in the database.

Comment: Just round at the very end. Round your SUM instead of each tax separately. As I understand, tax is paid on the final sum, so only it should be rounded. Otherwise, if the tax is paid for each item separately, then your query is right. This are two different formulas, neither is wrong, depends on how it is done in reality.

Comment: How do you think I should adjust my php logic then? My problem is that items can have varying taxes so every item can be taxed differently.

Comment: You round it on insertion in your database. You can't restore it if you rounded it off. What you can do is store it without rounding.

Comment: On a second thought, alternatively, don't read rounded taxes from the database at all. You can recalculate taxes using the original prices which are, alongside the percentages should be in the database as well.

Comment: I don't store any rounded values in the database just original price and tax percent.

Comment: I know I can recalculate, but I need to be able to do this all in the databases for performance reasons and that a lot of reports already rely on a big query (That didn't share on this...I am trying to simplify this problem as much as I can)

Comment: Your question seem to have nothing to do with mysql or php. There are two ways to calculate things: 1. Find tax, round, add. 2. Find tax, add, round. These two will give you different results. Only you (your accountant?) know if your tax should necessarily be rounded to cents or not.

Comment: You seem to be rounding every tax for each item, this seems wrong as you need to sum up the total percents and then find the total tax on the item. Each of those tax parts should not necessarily be a whole number of cents.

Comment: I cannot recall in detail, however, I do remember mysql has a data type issue, when it comes to use do the math round or ceil ...

I suggest you look into that.

Comment: You are just missing the feature where it "takes those remainders and puts it into your account."

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446581/mysql-round-weird-bug#answer-10446940

Comment: @Zac I am not use float or double..it is decimal. ficuscr that made me laugh

Comment: @sashkello I need to be able to calculate a tax value for each item in the sale as that is the way my reporting works. Is this strategy flawed? Should I apply the same logic to my php part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so, your question, as I understand it has not much to do with programming.

So, you have an item which is worth $1. Now, you have two taxes on it, one is 1.4% and another one is 1.3%. Now, this is what you are doing

```
tax1 = round($1*0.014, 2) = $0.01
tax2 = round($1*0.013, 2) = $0.01
totaltax = $0.02
```

So far so good... OK, but now let's do it other way. If we add up the taxes, we should pay the total of `1.4 + 1.3 = 2.7%`, which means:

```
totaltax = round($1*0.027, 2) = $0.03
```

See what happened here?

Now, which of these ways is right? If you physically need to pay tax1 separately from tax2, then each of them is quantified in cents and the first way is right. But, I feel like you most likely only pay the final total tax, that is you add up percents first, calculate your tax and then pay it to the nearest cent.

---

In relation to your code, you should get 1.03, that's right, but your query is doing a mistake similar to the first variant by rounding the result for each item before adding them up (it is doing `round(price1*tax1, 2) + round(price2*tax2, 2)`). (Actually, just to be complete, you have three places to round: individual tax level, item level and on the total level.)

To round at the end instead of for each item, move out your `ROUND`:

```
(SELECT ROUND(SUM(tax),2) FROM (SELECT (item_unit_price)*(SUM(percent)/100) as tax
FROM phppos_sales_items
INNER JOIN phppos_sales_items_taxes USING (sale_id, item_id)
WHERE sale_id = 1
GROUP BY sale_id, item_id) as tax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to put as an answer, since the comment can not display code properly.

How about

```
(SELECT ROUND(SUM(tax)/100,2) FROM (SELECT item_unit_price*SUM(percent) as tax
FROM phppos_sales_items
INNER JOIN phppos_sales_items_taxes USING (sale_id, item_id)
WHERE sale_id = 1
GROUP BY sale_id, item_id) as tax)
```

Can you export the tables as sql, so I can try on my local? If nothing is too confidential.

Comment: I dumbed down the sql structure a lot...there is a giant query that creates a temporary table and does all the calculations. If you are interested in helping I can offer compensation to analyze the problem and come up with a solution. If you look at my stackoverflow profile and then --> website, I have an email address listed. I can't offer much as I am on a low budget, but I tried to fix it for about 5 hours today with no luck. It only happens in a couple edge cases...I fixes it for one, and it breaks for the other.