# Rounding in mysql doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, mysql, casting, double, rounding

I can't understand why my results are different:

I have table **orders** and column **price** (type **double** in mysql).

The **price** value in database is **13.5**.

query:

```
SELECT ROUND(price * 0.09, 2) FROM orders where id = 1;
```

result is: **1.21**

query:

```
SELECT ROUND(13.5 * 0.09, 2);
```

the result is **1.22**

without rounding: `SELECT 13.5 * 0.09` result is **1.215**

so the correct result after round is **1.22**.

Why query `SELECT ROUND(price * 0.09, 2) FROM orders where id = 1;` gives me wrong result (1.21)?

I can't understand what's wrong, I guess something with casting.

Could someone explain me it?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446581/mysql-round-weird-bug

Comment: This url can be helpful about MySQL ROUND function  (http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-round-function.php)

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you would want DOUBLE for 'price'. See DECIMAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the end I converted my columns to decimal 15,2. I was a bit afraid about the risk with converting, after few tests there is no difference in total sum of prices. I recommend to do it for everyone who has this problem.

[Best data type to store money values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, so I write you an answer.

Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html

Float and Double data, don't store exact numbers, so It's possible to find weird issues.

Try to CEIL as AT-2016 told you, hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If datatype is float use cast
SELECT round(cast(qty as decimal(10,2))*0.99,2) FROM orders  WHERE 1